# I always don't vs I don't always

Tags: grammar

*I don't always get up early.
I always don't get up early.*
Are both of these sentences correct?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't always get up early

would be used to refute the assertion that you always got up early. E.g.

> I woke at 5. I don't always get up early, but today...

It is implied that you sometimes  get up early, but not always. Conversely:

> I always don't get up early

means that you never get up early (*I always do not...*). It is, however, poor grammar and should be expressed as

> I never get up early

or

> I always get up late.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.It's quite clear for me right now

Answer (score 0):

*I don't always get up early* seems to convey the message of I may not always get up early but sometimes I do. *I always don't get up early* pretty much means that I never get up early.

In both case, they are indeed correct but with different meaning.